# Android Studio - Gradle: compiling script into cache is very slow

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I created a new Android Studio project, but at the end of the project configuration, Android Studio before had downloaded Gradle archives and then it started a process called:

*Gradle: compiling script into cache*

The process has been started for several minutes and I do not understand why it is so slow
Someone can help me?

Thanks

I give you a screenshot of the process dialog:
[image: A screenshot of the process dialog]

## UPDATE

### I solved the problem by reinstalling Android Studio, thanks

Comment: did you upgrade to 3.1 or did you download the standalone and updated !

Comment: I had to delete the folder .gradle from the user folder for other issues and now it downloaded the latest version of gradle

Comment: Answers should be posted as answers, not as part of the question. We also don't tag with (SOLVED) or similar--the presence of an accepted answer is sufficient.

Comment: Post your `build.gradle` files.